iPhone Driver Not Installed, Waiting for Windows Update to Install the Driver for this iPhone
I am trying to remote debug a .NET MAUI app on an Apple iPhone device, and it says that I need iTunes installed.  I have iTunes installed, but I noticed that it isn't seeing my device at all?  The device is plugged in via USB, and I selected "Allow" on the prompt on the phone which asked if this PC should have access to photos.  I can also see that the device is charging.
This issue occurs with the Apple Devices UWP app, Apple iTunes UWP/WPF app, and with the binary 64-bit iTunes installer.  Running Windows Update and waiting doesn't result in any found drivers or installs.

I noticed that, while the iPhone does appear in the Device Manager, the drivers aren't actually fully installed.  I was able to manually download and install the drivers by performing the following:

Download the 64-bit Windows installer: https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win64
Used WinRAR to extract AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi from the downloaded installer .exe (or you can use your favorite archive tool).
Ran the following using PowerShell:

msiexec /a C:\filepath/to/AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\filepath/to/target/folder


In the new folder (TARGETDIR above), navigate to ./Common Files/Apple/Mobile Device Support/Drivers.  There should be 4 files here.  Right-click on the usbaapl64.inf file and select "Install" from the context menu.  Once successful, unplug your device and restart your Apple program on the PC (e.g. iTunes) and/or Visual Studio.

